# Blender 2.8 cannot save document, or cannot re-open a document (sculpting) and crashes my whole computer

Tags: performance

I run Mojave 10.14.6, 8 GB
My downloaded Blender 2.8 from the blender 's website two weeks ago.

It seems rather random. In sculpting mode, some files suddenly won't save. Instead the program freezes and crashes my computer. So turn off my computer and reopen it. When I try to re-open the problem file, the program freezes again and crashes my computer again. I keep loosing my work.

Do you know what is going on?
Thanks.

Comment: So since you're on a mac with 8 gb of ram, this makes me think that it's unable to render your model. Are you using any modifiers that have the rendering set a little high? Like higher than 2 or 3? You can upload your file here so people can download it
https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thanks for your response, Martin. Here is what I do: 1. I open in Sculpting and using "Decimate" I reduce the divisions by half.  2. I set "Dynotopo" at 20 pix. 3. After blocking my shapes, I up  "Dynotopo" res. to 30 pix, and as I zero in on details, I keep upping "Dynotopo res.", trying to limit the high res. to the area where I need details, and never higher than 50 pix. For the finest details, I switch from Constant to Relative details. I noticed that crashes often happened after I turned Dynotopo on or off.  I hope that helps. Thx.